# algorithm for the volume of the intersection of $m$ balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Is there an algorithm for computing the volume of the intersection of $m$ balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$? That is, we want to compute the volume of

$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^m \mathcal{B}(C_k,r)
$$  where $r > 0$ and $C_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|C_k\| = \|C_{k+1}\|$

I know about the existence of a polynomial randomized algorithm for approximating the volume of general convex bodies. My question is about the existence of an algorithm which takes advantage of the particular convex bodies: intersection of balls